# C# website, am I forced to use IIS?

Tags: c#, lamp, mod-mono

I've been thinking for a while about which language to use on my next project.  Usually I default to PHP on my LAMP server, but I'd really like to use C# (mainly because of code reuse), and ideally still sicking with Apache.  Has anyone used mod_mono on a live project, and if so what is the performance like?   The site is likely to get smashed to bits in terms of traffic.

Am I forced to go IIS if I want C#?  If not I'll stick to PHP via LAMP as usual.

Comment: Any use? http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx Bit dated, but might still be valid.

Comment: You could also look at using Mono http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Comment: Don't know what functionality you need but here is a C# webserver http://webserver.codeplex.com/ you can use

Comment: XSP is the latest/greatest web server from Mono. Further info can be found in the link @Jason provided.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.   I'm not sure about mod-mono stability or performance.  Maybe early adoption isn't such a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for the other links too (XSP, codeplex)

Comment: I'm liking the idea of XSP and FastCGI - I just wonder about performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no, one is not forced to use IIS for a C# website".  The suggestions above are mostly in alpha/beta development stage however and so using c# for a production website isn't advisable yet.